# How to assign data from database to a global variable

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to include foreign keys into my tables got from a database, one of the solutions i've come up with is to get all of the data and store them in a global variable to then use where they needed.

I've tried using a get within the current get's i have instead, though i'm sure that's not the best way of doing it as i would be getting the same data 2-3 times depending on the table called.

The error i am getting is:

> "js.js:205 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'R1000002' of undefined" line 205 is in the first snippet (`"fk_RouteStations[element.ROUTE_ID] = element;"`)

```
params = {
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  }
}

$.ajax({
  url: "...",
  type: "GET",
  data: params,
  success: function(result) {
    result.forEach(function(element) {
      fk_RouteStations[element.ROUTE_ID] = element;
    })
    console.log("Got ROUTE_STATIONS Data");
  }
}).fail(console.log("Failed to get ROUTE_STAITONS Data"));
```

```
//foreign keys
var fk_customer;
var fk_trains;
var fk_routes;
var fk_tickets;
var fk_carriages;
var fk_RouteStations;
var fk_staff;
var fk_stations;
```

```
else if (currentTable == "ROUTES") {
  var url = '...';
  var id = document.getElementById("searchField").value;
  const URL = url.concat(id);

  const params = {
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    }
  };

  console.log("Getting Routes Data");

  $.ajax({
    url: URL,
    type: "GET",
    data: params,
    success: function(result) {

      $("resultsDisplay").text("Got Results");
      //var fk_routes = JSON.stringify(result);
      var string = "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Price Per Stop</th><th>Route_stations</th><th>Tickets</th><th>Trains</th></tr>";
      console.log("Running results")

      if (id == "") {
        console.log("Displaying results as array");
        for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
          string += "<tr><td>" + result[i].ROUTE_ID + "</td><td>" + result[i].PRICEPERSTOP + "</td></tr>";
        }

        string += "</table>";
        document.getElementById("tables").innerHTML = string;
        document.getElementById("loadingPrompt").style.display = "none";
      } else {
        console.log("Displaying results as object")
        string += "<tr><td>" + result.ROUTE_ID + "</td><td>" + result.PRICEPERSTOP + "</td><td>" + fk_RouteStations[element].ROUTE_ID + "</td><td>" + "fk_tickets[0,1]" + "</td><td>" + "TRAINS" + "</td></tr>";
        string += "</table>";
        document.getElementById("tables").innerHTML = string;
        document.getElementById("loadingPrompt").style.display = "none";
      }

      makeSelectable();
    }
  }).fail(function() {
    document.getElementById("tables").innerHTML = "User not found";
  });
```

The expected output would be for the table to be showing the foreign keys correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: You're not returning `fk_RouteStations[element.ROUTE_ID] = element;`